# Who were the wise master of Yunkai's "powerful friends"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In season 3 of Game of Thrones, Daenerys holds a meeting with one of the wise masters of Yunkai. At the end of the meeting, he threatens her and says we have "powerful friends". After he leaves, Daenerys asks Jorah who he was talking about and Jorah doesn't know. Daenerys tells Jorah to find out.

So my question is, who were these powerful friends he was referring to? It couldn't have been the Second Sons as they're just a 2000 man army of sell swords (whereas Daenerys had 8000 unsullied). Is this possibly a plot thread that the show runners planted but decided to not follow up on?

Comment: Or there were no powerful friends and it was just a bluff? Also a possibility.

Comment: Would you like book related answers as well?

Comment: Don't think there's a show answer to this question but there are book answers if you're interested.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53420/how-could-ser-jorah-mormont-find-out-about-the-second-sons

Comment: Yunkai has no King, the city is governed by [Wise Masters](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wise_Masters)

Comment: @Mooz Sure, if you could put in spoiler tag. Do you think the book answers would have any baring on what could happen in season 6?

Comment: @kuhl If you could take a look at my response to Mooz since he pretty much said the same thing as you.

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark Yeah I saw this, but I disagree that it was the second sons that the wise master was referring to.

Comment: @NikaG. Thanks I corrected my post.

Comment: @gruntswilldie Yeah true but confusing for them not to acknowledge it as a bluff.

Comment: Probably they are referring to Astapor and Mereen, the other two cities of Slaver's Bay. You see, Yunkai is still on the belief that (while Astapor has already fallen), the great families of Mereen would be able to help them.

Comment: Remember that "500 men could hold Winterfell against a large army". Sieging Yunkai would make it quite hard for 8000 soldiers to win against 2000 well-trained Second Sons.

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark Yeah but something like that wouldn't deem a response like "we have powerful friends"

Comment: @gelolopez Why would they mention this on the show though? It would seem pointless to mention it and not follow up on it.

Comment: Well, the show always made no follow up. Look at Balon Greyjoy, Robert Arynn, Gendry, etc

Comment: Wouldn't know about the show but as per books their powerful friends were New Ghis, Tolos, Volantis & Meereen. Daenerys conquered the last one. The rest joined arms against her and besieged her there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct proof of the substance behind the threat (if there even was any). However, we can still speculate.

Note that I don't believe it was the Second Sons. First of all, they are outnumbered by the Unsullied, and the masters would not consider a bunch of sellswords as their friends.

---

### 1. It was an empty threat

I wouldn't put it past them to threaten something that they cannot follow up on. Daenerys is considered naive after all, and before Tyrion, most of her (political) advisors weren't considered that experienced either.

### 2. They are referring to their friends, the other masters

The masters in general seem to be relatively well coordinated among themselves. They could simply be referencing the other masters, assuming that Daenerys would not be capable of standing up to an alliance of the masters.

They could also be referencing another major player, who operates on a slightly higher level than the master of Yunkai. If I'm not mistaken, Qarth was considered on a higher level than the masters of Yunkai (deeper pockets, more influence). Maybe it's Qarth, or a similarly powerful city.

### 3. They are referring to a Westerosi partner.

Robert Baratheon had kept an eye on Daenerys (via Jorah). We've seen other instances of the throne (King's Landing) being aware of Daenerys' current state. It stands to reason that they have spies abroad to follow up on Daenerys.
It's possible they talked to the masters of Yunkai, as I would expect the masters to be the easiest to contact from abroad. Plus, they are merchants, so they should happily render services (spying) for money.

### 4. They have a currently unknown partner.

This is of course nothing but speculation, but it is possible that there is another big player who has not been identified yet in the story. Maybe they were waiting for Daenerys to leave for Westeros. Maybe they are a major plot point near the end of the story.

I doubt it, but it's not impossible.